# Are oysters really aphrodisiacs?

Tags: food, literature, sex

[Oysters have been thought of as aphrodisiacs for millennia.](https://theoystersmyworld.com/tag/casanova-and-oysters/)

Is this a case of the bark of a willow tree as a precursor to modern paracetamol, or some sort of marketing ploy.

Is there any biological evidence that foodstuffs such as lobsters, oysters and other sea delicacies boost our sexual health and desire? If so, what biological mechanism underlies this property?

Comment: What research have you done before asking it here?

Comment: Positively, a lot of people consider seafood an aphrodisiac for various reasons. I am interested in the scientific point of view.

Comment: Welcome to Bio. It feels more like a rumor than anything else. I am unfamiliar with the specific stack, but [Skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) may be more appropriate. The question as it stands may be anecdotal and it is too broad for this site. If you could add a credible source that claims your hypothesis, it would already improve your post. *Why* and *How* questions generally fair well here. 'Is *X* true questions' are generally much less well received.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I *think* it may be better suited for [Skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @LadyFickle To be answered in Skeptics.SE you will need to provide a *specific source* for the information which has to show that it is a *notable claim* (for example, something like a major newspaper publication, not a copy of a Facebook post). I am sure you can find such a source but you have to do that work rather than having us do it for you. Second, I somewhat disagree that this question doesn't belong here. I think if you provide a decent source we can answer it as a biology question.

Comment: (also note that "notable" doesn't mean you have to find a well-referenced source, just something to show that it isn't just speculation among a group of people but rather a wide-ranging idea, see [this meta](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable) )

Comment: I've heard this before. Apparently, oysters have been thought of as an aphrodisiac for millennia: https://theoystersmyworld.com/tag/casanova-and-oysters/

Comment: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1486054/Raw-oysters-really-are-aphrodisiacs-say-scientists-and-now-is-the-time-to-eat-them.html